# GCM Notification Title and Message in LockScreen (Android)

Tags: notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

I want to show a GCM Notification containing a title, message, and a large icon in the Lock Screen. The image and the title will be coming from my app where the title is my app's name and the notification belong to one signal service.

I want to make the notification same as below notification in the picture.

[image]

This is my code:

```
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);



    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);


    Bitmap small_Icon = getBitmapFromURL((String) extras.get(Config.SMALLICON_KEY));
    Bitmap large_Icon = getBitmapFromURL((String) extras.get(Config.LARGEICON_KEY));
    Bitmap Poster = getBitmapFromURL((String) extras.get(Config.BIGPICTURE_KEY));
    String title = (String) extras.get(Config.TITLE_KEY);
    String message = (String) extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon((R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(Poster)
                    .setBigContentTitle(title)
                    .setSummaryText(message))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLargeIcon(large_Icon);

    //////// Play Defult Notification Sound ////////
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    r.play();
    //////// End Play Defult Notification Sound ////////


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are aiming to do is a visible [Lock Screen Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#lockscreenNotification). As per the docs:

**Setting Visibility**

> Your app can control the level of detail visible in notifications displayed on a secure lock screen. You call `setVisibility()` and specify one of the following values: `VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`, `VISIBILITY_SECRET`, `VISIBILITY_PRIVATE`.

Also found this [Simple Tutorial on Lollipop Notifications](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-development-tutorial-lollipop-notifications/) that might be useful for you.